# Jquery Banner Slider

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 900 x 80 header area, and a 175 x 75 logo that fits in the upper left corner of this area.  What I want to do is use jquery to move the logo from the right of header area to the left, and freeze and set there on the left side.  I know this function sounds like it should be done in flash, but I am really wanting to use jquery.  Any ideas on a plugin to use, and how to implement it?  Or any suggestions for that matter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how it can be done.

**HTML**

```
<img src="xyz.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
img{
    position:absolute;
    left:400px;
    top:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$('img').animate({left :'0'})
```

### Check working example at http://jsfiddle.net/9YWWw/5/

Comment: does the HTML need to be in a "img" div? ei. <div class="img">

Comment: No it doesn't have to be img or div. You can reference it by it's ID, class or tag name. Ex: `$('#id')` or `$('.class')` or `$('p')` ...

Answer (score 0):

While not jQuery, [Tween.js](https://github.com/sole/tween.js/tree/) would be prefect for the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can [animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) your logo with jQuery.